# How to add padding left in react-pdf/renderer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react-pdf/renderer for displaying pdf . I am currently using dynamic text to show content of pdf. I want to add padding left to view which is inside the another view. I have applied various CSS properties to add padding but it is not working.

Below is my code.

```
<View style={styles.section}>
<Text >
  {'\n'}{today} {'\n'}{'\n'}
<View ><Text > <Text style={{ margingLeft : '50px' }}>⦁</Text> someValue {'\n'}</Text>
</View>
</Text>
</View>
```

I have also tried inline CSS.

If anyone knows solution. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: I think `margingLeft` should be `marginLeft` and instead of putting it inside your `Text` properties place it in the parent `View`

Comment: i dont want marginLeft in parent view. I need that in 2nd view.

Comment: Actually I have View in return and in that view i want padding left property